# How to bypass sip or rtp voip traffic in blocked networks using open vpn?

Tags: android, sip, vpn, openvpn, tunnel

I am newbie in openvpn,We are using openvpn android application to route Our VoIP traffic using Android. In our application we are using sip / rtp port.

We are using free [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/) account from [this](http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn)

Our vpn is successfully created but still we are not able to register our voip application using same user account (sip account). May be some port blocking from [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/) server which we are using to connect.

Please also suggest if there is any other way to fulfill my scenario. Make sip / rtp traffic working in blocked network with android device.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Waiting for positive reply.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on how is your current setup? When you connect to the VPN does your IP address changes? Dose your sip server support TLS? which VPN service do you have?

Comment: We are using openVPN server in VM. And we are using openvpn application of android to connect this vpn. After connecting vpn our ip is changed. We are using openVPN service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we get the solution and here it is. 
We have check openvpn application
You can download the openvpn app from [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn)

we have setup in detail and we have found that there are already option to allow other install app to use this connected vpn or not. So we have just manage it programmatically. And yes in our vpn the all sip port and ip is open to use, so it will works as per our requirement.

For the app setting you can see this image.
[image]